# Ajax request returns 'Array'. How to output the actual results?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to output the results of the SQL statement into the select#input_6_26 option.  The code is running and the Ajax request is properly requesting the PHP function, however it's only outputting the word 'Array' and not the actual results. I **think** I'm needing to ask how to set the results to an array and properly output those. Any help would be appreciated!

Setting Ajax shortcode for URL:

```
function add_ajaxurl_cdata_to_front(){ ?>
<script type="text/javascript"> //<![CDATA[
    ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
//]]> </script>
<?php }
add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_ajaxurl_cdata_to_front', 1);

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'add_js_to_wp_footer' );
function add_js_to_wp_footer() { ?>
```

Ajax Call:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery("#field_6_17 select").on('change', function() {

    var product_line = jQuery(this).val();

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: {
          "action": "view_site_description",
          first_name : 'John',           // PHP: $_POST['first_name']
          last_name  : 'Cena',
        }, success: function(data){
          jQuery('select#input_6_26 option').html(data);
        }
    });
     return false;
    });
    </script>
    <?php }
```

PHP Function:

```
function view_site_description(){
global $wpdb;
$choices = [];

$termId = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT term_id FROM wp_terms WHERE name = 'Baffles'");

  foreach($termId as $termIds) {

    $objectId = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT object_id FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id = $termIds->term_id");

      foreach($objectId as $objectIds) {

        $postId = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE id = $objectIds->object_id AND post_status = 'publish'");

          foreach($postId as $postIds) {

            $choices = array("text" => $postIds->post_title, "value" => $postIds->post_title);
          }
      }
  }

  echo $choices;
  die();
  }
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_view_site_description', 'view_site_description' );
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_view_site_description', 'view_site_description' );
```

Comment: to transform the array in JSON and send it, you can use `wp_send_json($choices);`

Comment: That results in echoing out blank results in the select element.